# Cannot read property 'fantasy-land/map' of undefined Dash DataTable Updating table with dropdowns

Tags: python, reactjs, plotly, plotly-dash

I am referencing the sample code snippet that @chriddyp posted here https://community.plot.ly/t/dash-datatable-updating-rows-with-dropdowns/6714 and the discussions that happened on the linked posts

Reproducible example

```
import flask
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table_experiments as dt
import pandas as pd

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State


def create_dropdown_list(df, column):
    dd = df.loc[:, [column]].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
    dd['label'] = dd[column]
    dd = dd.rename(columns={column:'value'}).to_dict(orient='records')
    return dd


city_temp = pd.DataFrame({'City':['Montreal','New York','San Francisco'], 
                          'Temperature':[68,83,66]})


server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(server=server, )

dropdown_list = create_dropdown_list(city_temp, 'City')

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown',
        options=dropdown_list, # which looks like [{'label': 'Montreal', 'value': 'Montreal'}, {'label': 'New York', 'value': 'New York'}, {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'San Francisco'}]
        value = 'Montreal'
        ),
    html.H4(children='My table'),
    dt.DataTable(id='my-datatable')
])


@app.callback(Output('my-datatable', 'rows'), [Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_rows(selected_value):
    city_temp_sub = city_temp[city_temp.City == selected_value].reset_index(drop=True)
    return city_temp_sub.to_dict('records')

app.css.append_css({
    'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'
})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

I get the "Error loading dependencies" on the browser
And on the console I get the error as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fantasy-land/map' of undefined"

Can someone help ?

Thank you

Anuj

Comment: This is the same as this post, check there for more info. https://community.plot.ly/t/cannot-read-property-fantasy-land-map-of-undefined-dash-datatable-updating-table-with-dropdowns/12958/. You will have a better chance of getting questions answered on the plotly community forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

Dash's DataTable needs to be initialized with empty `rows` to work properly.

```
dt.DataTable(id='my-datatable', rows=[{}])
```

**Long answer**

Reducing the code to its minimum helps spotting the issue.

```
import flask
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table_experiments as dt

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(server=server, )

app.layout = html.Div([
    dt.DataTable(id='my-datatable', rows=[{}])
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

The underlying problem is hidden in the source code:
https://github.com/plotly/dash-table-experiments/blob/1e5b24eec53627418c51027f561cb7bae591a95e/dash_table_experiments/metadata.json

The argument `rows` is neither `required`, nor does it have a default value.

```
"rows": {
    "type": {
      "name": "arrayOf",
      "value": {
        "name": "custom",
        "raw": "PropTypes.shape"
      }
    },
    "required": false,
    "description": ""
  },
```